# React how to address a key from string name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, api, relational

Ok, so I have a database with data sets in it. the application performs a base API call to retrieve that base data set containing all other data sets. I will receive a string variable with the name of the key I need to access so let's say const addon = "Book". However, I don't know the key name beforehand. So the following code works but I need to somehow not hard code the key parameter but rather use the string value incoming from the const addon. I am not quite sure how to do this please point me to the right documentation or explain how to achieve the wanted result.

```
const columns = levelOne.Book && Object.keys(levelOne.Book);
```

However, as the incoming param might not be "Book" but anything else it will only work for this case. It is guaranteed that there is a key-value pair where the key bears the name stored in the string value of addon.

Comment: You can use brackets to access a key of an object based on a variable. For example, `levelOne[someVariable]` where `someVariable` might be the string `"Book"` or maybe it'll be something else

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `variable` as the key. For example, `levelOne[variable]` where `variable` is the string that you want to use as the key.
Also, you can get the keys through `Object.keys(levelOne)` and then you can set `variable` value from the keys array.